# Resize the pagecontrolview of detailViewController when i turn iPad to Portrait mode in UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am working on UISplitViewController, I have a pageController in my detail view of width 700, I have added some imageViews on the pageController, when i turn my iPad to portrait mode how to resize the pageController so that the even the imageViews should fit to width 768.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be use the autoresizing mask. And when you properly use autoresizingMask then that view controller will be resize automatically when you change the orientation.

Let me know if this answer help you ..

Comment: You also add autoresizingMake by programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but got another issue....when i resize the pageController, im am giving the option of subViewsResizing also to YES, but the imageView on the pageController is not getting resized.....any help???

Comment: Thanks @SmartDeveloper....You helped me a lot....by your answer i used this and worked [viewObj setAutoresizingMask : (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin)] ;